# How to view jms queues in activemq after adding failover transport?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, master-slave

I seem to be having trouble viewing my jms queues after applying failover transport to activemq. The queues can be viewed from the master using the usual url `http://localhost:8162/admin/queues.jsp`, but it does not work when tried on the slave. I need to see the queues created when the master is down and the slave takes over. Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: have you created master slave configuration ?
if yes, do both point to same data repository?

Comment: Do you mean the kahaDB data directory? yes both point to a shared folder in Master's `C:/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When both master and slave point to same folder for data repository this arrangement is called 'Master slave configuration with shared database', in this case following things occur

- when your master node starts up, it acquires a lock on this database
  and it starts up successfully, so you can access this nodes details
  from UI.
- but when a slave node starts up, it tries to gain lock of the database
  , but as it is already locked by master node, it cant gain the lock
  and keeps on polling the DB for lock and doesnt startup(This is an expected and correct behaviour)
- Now whenever master node fails , it releases the lock and this lock
  is gained by slave node(as it is continuously polling the DB),now it
  gains the lock and starts up, by this only one node is up at any
  given time and if that node fails slave node starts up

in your case, if you shut down your master node you will surely be able to access slave node from UI

Hope this helps!

Good luck!